# Wordpress 3.7 two sidebars registration

Tags: wordpress, sidebar

I am trying to register two sidebars in my custom theme whit this code in my `function.php`:

```
if ( function_exists( 'register_sidebar' ) ) {
register_sidebar( array (
'name' => __( 'Primary Sidebar', 'primary-sidebar' ),
'id' => 'primary-widget-area',
'description' => __( 'The primary widget area', 'dir' ),
'before_widget' => '<div class="widget">',
'after_widget' => "</div>",
'before_title' => '<h3 class="widget-title">',
'after_title' => '</h3>',
) );


register_sidebar( array (
'name' => __('Sidebar Widget Area', 'blankslate'),
'id' => 'primary-widget-area',
'before_widget' => '<li id="%1$s" class="widget-container %2$s">',
'after_widget' => "</li>",
'before_title' => '<h3 class="widget-title">',
'after_title' => '</h3>',
) );
}
```

But it's not working.

It registers second sidebar but not first . I am using WordPress 3.7 and **blankslate** as "framework" theme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose the `id` should be unique.

Comment: Thank you, I did not see that. I am pretty tired :)